# How can I put a black square in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm2e

I used to write pseudocode in libreoffice and it looked like this:[image: libreoffice-pseudocode]

I'm trying to write something similar in latex.I use algorithm2e.This is the closest thing I got.[image: algorithm2e]

How can I put a black square at the of the while?

This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\textbf{positive integers }$a,b,r$\;
\textbf{read } $a,b$\;
\While{$ b \neq 0 $}{
$r \gets a\%b$\;
$a \gets b$\;
$b \gets r$\;
\qed
}
\textbf{print } $a$\;

\textbf{positive integers }$a,b,r$\;
\textbf{read } $a,b$\;
\While{$ b \neq 0 $}{
$r \gets a\%b$\;
$a \gets b$\;
$b \gets r$\;
}\qed
\textbf{print } $a$\;


\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

And I get this:
[image: not good]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I change `\algocf@Hlne` that is responsible for adding the bottom stub of the L-shaped rule, adding a vertically-centred black square.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@Hlne}{%
  \rule{.5em}{.4pt}% horizontal rule
  \smash{\rule[\dimexpr-.5ex+.2pt]{1ex}{1ex}}% ending block
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \textbf{positive integers }$a,b,r$\;
  \textbf{read } $a,b$\;
  \While{$ b \neq 0 $}{
    $r \gets a\%b$\;
    $a \gets b$\;
    $b \gets r$\;
  }
  \textbf{print } $a$\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
   \hbox{\vbox{\vspace*{3pt}$\blacksquare$\vspace*{-3pt}}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\textbf{positive integers }$a,b,r$\;
\textbf{read } $a,b$\;
\While{$ b \neq 0 $}{
$r \gets a\%b$\;
$a \gets b$\;
$b \gets r$\;
\qed}
\textbf{print } $a$\;

\textbf{positive integers }$a,b,r$\;
\textbf{read } $a,b$\;
\While{$ b \neq 0 $}{
$r \gets a\%b$\;
$a \gets b$\;
$b \gets r$\;
\qed}
\textbf{print } $a$\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i'm not able to check this since i don't have an available tex system at the moment.)  since `amsthm` is loaded, what happens at `\end{proof}` to the qed box if the document also contains a theorem with a proof?

Comment: OP didn't mentioned this If we need to use \end{proof} we can use new command instead of `\qed`  like this `\necommand{\square}{\hbox{\vbox{\vspace*{3pt}$\blacksquare$\vspace*{-3pt}}}}`

Comment: It's useful, but it doesn't look very neat. Is there a way to eliminate the white space between the horizontal line and the box?